# Two versions of the same Java class where each has a different superclass

Tags: java, android, oop, dry

What is the cleanest way in Java to write two versions of the same class where each has a different superclass? By cleanest I mean DRY (least duplicated code). The two classes will have similar but different names and the same code.

The application is Android: class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity. Class MyActivity34 (for API level 3/4) extends Activity but has the same code as MyActivity. I don't want to keep two copies of everything (in C++ I would use the preprocessor for this). Changing the superclasses is not an option.

Thanks.

Note: The ActionBarActivity class can't be used at API level 3 or 4 (runtime error), so MyActivity34 can't have it anywhere in the inheritance path.

Comment: If they both contain the same code, move all of that code to a third class and have you first two classes *delegate* to that third class.

Comment: `ActionBarActivity` extends `Activity`. Why don't you create an abtract class with all the code you need same in both classes and then you create two classes extending that super one?

Comment: If I understand your idea correctly, the abstract class would have to extend one of the superclasses, ActionBarActivity, not Activity. The ActionBarActivity class can't be used at API level 3 or 4 (runtime error).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an interface ,say, `MyCommonActivityInterface` with all the methods

```
public interface MyCommonActivityInterface {
    public void sayHello();
    public void sayGoodbye();
}
```

Create a common activity with all the code

```
public class MyCommonActivity implements MyCommonActivityInterface {
    ...
    public void sayHello() {Log.d("MyCommonActivity", "says hello")};
    public void sayGoodbye() {Log.d("MyCommonActivity", "says goodbye")};
    ...
}
```

Now you can reuse the common code in both Activities

```
public class MyActivity34 extends Activity {
    MyCommonActivityInterface common = new MyCommonActivity();
    public void sayHello() {common.sayHello()};
    public void sayGoodbye() {common.sayGoodbye()};
}

public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    MyCommonActivityInterface common = new MyCommonActivity();
    public void sayHello() {common.sayHello()};
    public void sayGoodbye() {common.sayGoodbye()};
}
```

Well actually the interface can be omitted, but will come handy if you need to swap between alternatives or the like.

I have become really impressed by the powers of Dependency Injection, which can make these kind of things much cleaner.

There is a library called [Dagger](http://square.github.io/dagger/) that adds DI support for android. It has a somewhat steep learning curve but for me it was all worth it.

In this example you would be able to do stuff like:

```
@Singleton
public class MyCommonActivity  {

    // Example with context to show that it will be automagically injected

    @Inject
    public MyCommonActivity(@ForActivity Context context) {}
    ...
    public void sayHello() {Log.d("MyCommonActivity", "says hello")};
    public void sayGoodbye() {Log.d("MyCommonActivity", "says goodbye")};
    ...
}

public class MyActivity34 extends Activity {

    @Inject MyCommonActivity common;

    public void sayHello() {common.sayHello()};
    public void sayGoodbye() {common.sayGoodbye()};
}

public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Inject MyCommonActivity common;

    public void sayHello() {common.sayHello()};
    public void sayGoodbye() {common.sayGoodbye()};
}
```

With a lot of independent classes of code, where some depends on others, or needs a Context object etc,.. simply adding a @Inject line when and where ever you need it saves many lines of code!

And while we are add it, have a look at [ButterKnife](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife), much simpler but also only works for injecting Views. Still pretty darn powerful and neat.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably say your best bet is to use composition to encapsulate any duplicate code. Create a class which contains all the shared code and call it from the MyActivity and MyActivity34 classes. Often composition is better/cleaner than strange inheritance structures.